# save a number from one webpage on the server side and being able to retrieve it

Tags: php, jquery, html, web

i have a website for E-invoice. I'm trying to find the best way where i can retrieve a number "in my case the invoice number" and when creating a new invoice the old number will be saved somewhere and retrieved to be +1.

for now i know that i can't use cookies or session of course and i can't use HTML5 local storage to save the last invoice number and i know that it have to be something on the server side.

can i use xml or save the value in a text file then retrieve it? can anyone please inform me of the best approach to do this.

Comment: store it in a database when the invoice number is generated then just increment from the last one.

Comment: @Jacob I'm not using a database in my project that means that i will have to use one just for this little thing, really unpractical. Thanks anyways

Comment: ok, then the solution below is probably your best and simplest option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a possible solution (untested)

```
<?php
$file = fopen("number.txt","rw");
$number = fread($file);
$number += 1;  //the new number to proceed
fwrite($file,$number);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped, i used your code and did some edits on it:<?php $filename = "num.txt";
$file = fopen("num.txt","r+");
$number = fread($file, filesize($filename));
$number = $number + 1;  
file_put_contents('num.txt', $number);
fclose($file); >?